# The term 'Cleaning' in Django

Tags: django

```
class EnhancedArticleForm(ArticleForm):
    def clean_pub_date(self):
```

This is an example from the Djangobook. When we say 'clean' in Django, what does it actually mean? I am having some difficulty trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a naming convention for doing custom validation on one or more form / model form fields. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[Clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data)ing is nothing but normalizing it to a consistent (applicable) format.

Every time the form validates, (`form.is_valid()`) it runs the `clean()` and the `clean_<fields>()` for the form, and if there are errors, raises the Validation exceptions.

For example, lets say you have an application which accepts emails only from specific domains, lets say `abc.com`, `cnn.com` and `bbc.com`

Now, if someone tries to register with lets say `xyz.com`, the the best place to check for this and raise a validation error message would be the form field's `clean` method.

example:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    def clean_email(self): #clean_<fieldname> is the convention for "clean"ing a specific field
        email =  self.cleaned_data['email']
        #other validations here
        if not email.split('@')[1] in ['abc.com', 'bbc.com', 'cnn.com']:
            raise ValidationError('Select from following domains.. ')
        return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

Now this was a trivial example.

It could get a little more complicated like: if the domain is in `['abc.com', 'bbc.com', 'cnn.com']`, user has to check the checkbox agreeing to special terms and conditions specified on the form.

For that you can refer [Validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

This should give a basic usecase of `clean` and its usage.